# ie8 - margin and ajax bug

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, internet-explorer-8

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

bug 1 - http://perfectgsm.hu

Nivo Slider in the middle, in IE8 the top is not in line (in everything else its correct).
Inline margin-top:-12px inside, but in IE8 dev mode its looks as overridden by something.

(looks like in IE8 the div starts, but the content of it is starts above it)

---

bug 2 - http://perfectgsm.hu

the vertical gold menu on the top, on hovering any element has a weird movement to its buttons

(looks like the problem of the fella:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470418/ie8-vertical-margin-bug
)

---

bug 3 - http://konzolbazis.hu

ajax search not working...in the header there is a search, on typing it should refresh the table with ID=ajax, in other browsers it works like a charm.

(used a code from w3schools as a basic for it, linked below, and it works in ie8:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp
)

Comment: It's not good practice to use negative values for margin and padding. That's why u r getting bug : 1 and pls provide some code so that we can suggest the possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

Search bug solved: IE8 does not support js .innerHTML changing the content of a TR, so have to use a DIV.

Others still open.